# Min Max Difference by Different Groups in R

Tags: r

Would like to check how can I compute the date difference of max of personal ID 1 minus min of personal ID 2? Followed by max of personal ID 2 minus min of personal ID 3

```
|PersonalID|Min          |Max.       |
|:————————-|:——————————-:|—————————-:|
|1         | 01/01/2022  |31/01/2022 |
|2         | 01/03/2022  |31/03/2022 |
|2         | 01/04/2022  |30/04/2022 |
|3         | 01/06/2022  |30/06/2022 |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lagged difference by group with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474433/lagged-difference-by-group-with-dplyr)

Comment: The above link should answer your question. You can ignore the grouping part, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? We can convert each column to `Date`, then get the difference using `lead`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Min = as.Date(Min, "%m/%d/%Y"),
         Max = as.Date(Max, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         diff = Max - lead(Min))
```

**Output**

```
  PersonalID        Min        Max     diff
1          1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31  28 days
2          2 2022-01-03 2022-03-31  86 days
3          2 2022-01-04 2022-04-30 114 days
4          3 2022-01-06 2022-06-30  NA days
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(PersonalID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Min = c("01/01/2022", 
"01/03/2022", "01/04/2022", "01/06/2022"), Max = c("31/01/2022", 
"31/03/2022", "30/04/2022", "30/06/2022")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate that :)